# Comparing three fields

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table in which there are three fields

```
1. city
2. name
3. country
```

I am available with auto suggest in single Search field as comma seperated values for above given three fields, Now when I write anything on Text field of search and click search i must get all relevant resault. But my query seems to wrong as

I have writtent the WHERE clause as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city LIKE '%$xyz%' OR name LIKE '%$xyz%' OR country LIKE '%$xyz%'
```

NOTE: while giving input in the search field I DO NOT SELECT ANY AUTOSUGGESTED VALUE

Please Help me to Rectify my query

Comment: Do you obtain any error message?

Comment: thanks @ajreal for specific editing

Comment: @OM The Eternity can you post you PHP code around the query and how it is built?

Comment: Could you please post an example of your search term as well as some sample data from your table. Maybe there just aren't any results to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes in your LIKE clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city LIKE '%$xyz%' OR name LIKE '%$xyz%' OR country LIKE '%$xyz%'
```

Comment: It might not be the only reason, but it is a reason.  Have you tried it?

Comment: No i was wrong in inputting my question I have single quotes around my query, there must be other reason

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name like '%$name%' OR country like '%$country%' OR city like '%$city%'
```